# How to change two-dimension label to one-dimension label?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a two-dimension (10,2) coordinate which indicates each points label, like

```
coord_list = [(19, 17), (19, 17), (5, 26), (19, 17), (5, 26), (5, 26), (15, 17), (19, 5), (18, 6), (5, 26)]
```

I want to change it to a label list that only have one dimension (10,1),(assign a "label" to every unique item and replace each item by its label),like

```
label_list = [1,1,0....2,3]
```

I just want to classified points that have same coordinate in a same label, is there some more simple way can achieve it?
I tried to use this code,

```
label_list = []
for idx, coord in enumerate(coord_list):
    if coord == (19,17):
        label = 1
        label_list.append(label)
    if ...
```

But the problem is I don't know how many different coordinate in my coord_list, so I cannot write all if sentence in my code

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Same coordinate in a same label". Do you want to assign a "label" to every unique item and replace each item by its label?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Thanks for your reminding again and I revise my question, actually I am afraid I don't have very clear idea in my code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I think you're after.  I convert the list to a set, which eliminates duplicates.  Then back to a list, and I sort it.  Then I map each element of the original list to its index in that sorted list.  There are only 5 unique points here, so the indexes will be from 0 to 4:

```
coord_list = [(19, 17), (19, 17), (5, 26), (19, 17), (5, 26), (5, 26), (15, 17), (19, 5), (18, 6), (5, 26)]

a = sorted(list(set(coord_list)))
print(a)
b = [a.index(i) for i in coord_list]
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[(5, 26), (15, 17), (18, 6), (19, 5), (19, 17)]
[4, 4, 0, 4, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2, 0]
```